# Converting int to char in C# not working properly

Tags: c#, char, type-conversion, int

I'm trying to do some basic letters to int and back to chars. Converting `char` to `int` is fine, and I do this like so:

```
// text is a string taken from a text document, only english characters A-z
int[] letters = new int[text.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
       letters[i] = text[i] - 64;
    }
```

which produces an array of integers where A = 1, B = 2 etc. as expected. However, when I try to cast the array of ints back to `char`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((char)letters[i] + " (" + letters[i] + ")");
    }
```

I get random weird characters or no character at all (int in parenthesis):

(10)

(11)

(12)

(13)

(14) ...

I've tried both `Convert.ToChar()` and just the normal `(char)letter` cast and both yield the same result, and searched for topics on here on how to solve this but haven't found anything.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add 64 back before casting to char and printing it out on console.